# How to send data from node js to axios to react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http, axios

I am currently building a web app in react js and have stumbled onto axios. I am new to axios and have very little experience with it. Up until now, I have just been using fetch requests for my http request from my react app to my node / express server. Currently I have my node server calling a MySQL query. Here is that get request:

```
app.get('/getAllBusinessAccountsTransactions', function(request, response) {
var {userID, accountID} = request.query;
const getAllBusinessAccountsTransactions = `CALL GetUniqueBusinessUniqueAccountTransactions('${userID}', '${accountID}')`;

mysqlConnection.query(getAllBusinessAccountsTransactions, (error, result) => {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('SUCCESSFULLY RETRIEVED THE TRANSACTIONS!!!');
        var test = {result};

        console.log({"test": test.result[0]});
        response.status(200).send(
            {"blah": test.result[0]}
        )
    }
})
})
```

This get request seems to work fine. When I print out the result with console.log({"test": test.result[0]}); here is the response I get:

> `{ test: [ RowDataPacket { TransactionID: 38, Date: '0000-00-00', Description: 'test', Debit: 50, Credit: 0, Connection: 'undefined', AccountID: 19 }, RowDataPacket { TransactionID: 39, Date: '0000-00-00', Description: 'test two', Debit: 50, Credit: 0, Connection: 'undefined', AccountID: 19 }, RowDataPacket { TransactionID: 40, Date: '0000-00-00', Description: 'a', Debit: 50, Credit: 0, Connection: 'undefined', AccountID: 19 } ] }`

The result looks alright to me. Here is the axios function I use in my react app to call this get request.

```
getProducts () {
        var accountIDValue = '19';
        return axios.get('http://localhost:8080/getAllBusinessAccountsTransactions?userID=' + localStorage.getItem('currentUserID') + '&accountID=' + accountIDValue)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('TEST MY NEW AXIOS');
                console.log(response.data.blah);
            })   
    }
```

Again, when I test print the result of the axios request, I get the expected array of objects. Now here is where I suspect that my error is coming from. Here is the relevant code, in which I call the previous axios function:

```
const DataTableResponsiveDemo = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const productService = new ProductService();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('GOLLY TESTING');
        console.log(productService.getProducts());
        productService.getProducts().then(blah => setProducts(blah));
    }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

I am not getting an error with this code...meaning my web app will not crash. However, I am trying to populate a table with the data from where this function sets the data to state. However, when I print out the result of calling the function with console.log(productService.getProducts()); I get this strange behavior printed in my console:

[image]

So in summary, my query in my node get request retrieves the expected data. The data is sent to my axios function correctly (at least upon printing it as it retrieves the data from node). However, when I call the axios function, I get this weird promise pending message and my array of objects is not present. Is this possibly an error with the way I am sending the data from my node get request? I do apologize if this might seem like a simple problem...like I said, I am currently trying to learn about axios and am having a hard time figuring out what the problem is. Thanks so much in advance for the help!

Comment: getProducts () {
        var accountIDValue = '19';
        return axios.get('http://localhost:8080/getAllBusinessAccountsTransactions?userID=' + localStorage.getItem('currentUserID') + '&accountID=' + accountIDValue)
            .then((response) => {
                response.json()
            }).then(res => res).catch(err => console.log(err.message)
    }


Kindly try this and let me know what's up

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your getProducts function should be async since it is making an http request.

```
async getProducts() {
    var accountIDValue = '19';
    return await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/getAllBusinessAccountsTransactions?userID=' + localStorage.getItem('currentUserID') + '&accountID=' + accountIDValue));   
}
```

Then in your effect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('GOLLY TESTING');
    console.log(productService.getProducts());
    const response = productService.getProducts();
    setProducts(response.data);
}, []);
```

I think the missing piece here was the async/await bit. I believe the .then statement you have would still work as you had it but this is an alternate way to do that. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: This did not work. I still have the promise pending issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: What about `productService.getProducts().then(data => setProducts(data));` instead of the last 2 lines in the useEffect fn?

Comment: Upon further investigation, I am still getting the promise pending message. However, promise result has gone from undefined to Array. How do I change my useEffect to utilize the array that is now in promise result?

Comment: Yes, I just switched that line in use effect back. It will now populate my table with the same number of lines as are in my array...but no data yet...

Comment: Try `.then(response => setProducts(response.data))` and if that doesn't work, then put the call to getProducts() in an async function and await the result in the effect.